# Showing the ADM-Mass of Schwarzschild-Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass, adm-formalism

Can someone show that the ADM-Mass of Schwarzschild is identical with the Mass-Parameter?

Comment: See section 7.3.1 and 7.3.2 from [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035v1)

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you understand how he gets from equation 7.13 to 7.14. ?